# Argo artifacts gives error "http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client"

Tags: http, workflow, artifact, minio, argo-workflows

I was setting up Argo in my k8s cluster in Argo namespace.

I also Installed MinIO as an Artifact repository (https://github.com/argoproj/argo-workflows/blob/master/docs/configure-artifact-repository.md).

I am configuring a workflow which tries to access that Non-Default Artifact Repository as:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Workflow
metadata:
  generateName: artifact-passing-
spec:
  entrypoint: artifact-example
  templates:
  - name: artifact-example
    steps:
    - - name: generate-artifact
        template: whalesay
    - - name: consume-artifact
        template: print-message
        arguments:
          artifacts:
          # bind message to the hello-art artifact
          # generated by the generate-artifact step
          - name: message
            from: "{{steps.generate-artifact.outputs.artifacts.hello-art}}"

  - name: whalesay
    container:
      image: docker/whalesay:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cowsay hello world | tee /tmp/hello_world.txt"]
    outputs:
      artifacts:
      # generate hello-art artifact from /tmp/hello_world.txt
      # artifacts can be directories as well as files
      - name: hello-art
        path: /tmp/hello_world.txt
        s3:
          endpoint: argo-artifacts-minio.argo:9000
          bucket: my-bucket
          key: /my-output-artifact.tgz
          accessKeySecret:
            name: argo-artifacts-minio
            key: accesskey
          secretKeySecret:
            name: argo-artifacts-minio
            key: secretkey

  - name: print-message
    inputs:
      artifacts:
      # unpack the message input artifact
      # and put it at /tmp/message
      - name: message
        path: /tmp/message
        s3:
          endpoint: argo-artifacts-minio.argo:9000 
          bucket: my-bucket
          accessKeySecret:
            name: argo-artifacts-minio
            key: accesskey
          secretKeySecret:
            name: argo-artifacts-minio
            key: secretkey
    container:
      image: alpine:latest
      command: [sh, -c]
      args: ["cat /tmp/message"]
```

I created the workflow in argo namespace by:

```
argo submit --watch artifact-passing-nondefault-new.yaml -n argo
```

But the workflow fails with an error:

```
STEP                       PODNAME                           DURATION  MESSAGE

 ✖ artifact-passing-z9g64                                              child 'artifact-passing-z9g64-150231068' failed
 └---⚠ generate-artifact   artifact-passing-z9g64-150231068  12s       failed to save outputs: Get https://argo-artifacts-minio.argo:9000/my-bucket/?location=: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

Can someone help me to solve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the minio setup runs without TLS configured, the workflow should specify that it should connect to an insecure artifact repository.

Including a field `insecure: true` in the s3 definition section of the workflow solves the issue.

```
    s3:
      endpoint: argo-artifacts-minio.argo:9000
      insecure: true
      bucket: my-bucket
      key: /my-output-artifact.tgz
      accessKeySecret:
        name: argo-artifacts-minio
        key: accesskey
      secretKeySecret:
        name: argo-artifacts-minio
        key: secretkey
```